# Wrap simple JavaScript plugin using JsInterop

Tags: javascript, gwt, gwt2

i'm currently upgrading my **Gwt 2.7** project to **2.8-beta1** and i'm trying to refactor the Javascript plugin wrapper from **JSNI** to **JsInterop**.

Here the JSNI wrapper :

```
public class MyPlugin extends JavaScriptObject {

    protected MyPlugin(){
    }

    public static native MyPlugin init(MyPluginConfig config) /*-{
        return new $wnd.MyPlugin(config);
    }-*/;

    public final native void addItem(MyPluginItem item) /*-{
        this.addItem(item);
    }-*/;

    public final native void setEnable(int itemIndex, boolean enable) /*-{
        this.setEnable(itemIndex, enable);
    }-*/;
}
```

What i've tried :

```
@JsType(namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL, isNative = true)
public class MyPlugin {
    public static native MyPlugin init(MyPluginConfig config);
    public native void addItem(MyPluginItem item);
    public native void setEnable(int itemIndex, boolean enable);
}
```

The problem, i have no idea how to wrap the constructor. 
In the [JsInterop doc](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit-contributors/L6uh96NcZtE/XUwhnsAg7TIJ)

> A native @JsType class can only have
>       Public native methods,
>       Public and uninitialized fields,
>       **Empty constructor**,
>       Final non-native methods that doesn’t override any other methods,

So, this is my question : How to wrap a JavaScript plugin where in the JS the constructor looks like `var myPlugin = MyPlugin({option1 : value1, option2 : value2,...});` in JsInterop ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution.

Just declare a constructor with params and empty content :

```
@JsType(namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL, isNative = true)
public class MyPlugin {
    public MyPlugin(MyPluginConfig config) {} //<--- here
    public native void addItem(MyPluginItem item);
    public native void setEnable(int itemIndex, boolean enable);
}
```

And it works.

Hope it helps other people :)

**EDIT : MyPluginConfig structure**

MyPluginConfig is just a POJO class.

```
@JsType(namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL, isNative = true, name = "Object")
public class MyPluginConfig {
    @JsProperty public void setXXXX(String str);
    @JsProperty public String getXXXX();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you share your MyPluginConfig code structure? I'm trying to pass options to my wrapper, but its breaking.

Comment: Hello can you share?

Comment: @xybrek. should work:

`
@JsType(isNative = true, namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL)
public class MyPluginConfig {
    public String option1; 
    public int option2;
}
`

`
MyPluginConfig config = new MyPluginConfig();
config.option1 = "some string option";
config.option2 = 101;
MyPlugin plugin = new MyPlugin(config);
`